# Process in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have some questions about Hyperledger Fabric:

1. How dose a blockchain work in hyperledger composer and fabric?

2. In Hyperledger Fabric, you don't use a miner, how does it work without mining in a blockchain?

3. In hyperledger composer use JavaScript write transaction (smart contract), how does it work with a blockchain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi I would suggest to read the docs to get a better understanding.

1. Fabric http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blockchain.html and https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/introduction/introduction.html  - it should be pretty clear from reading the introduction pages.

Hyperledger Composer simplifies application development on top of the Hyperledger Fabric blockchain infrastructure.

If you are interested in the blockchain infrastructure, start with the Fabric tutorials.

If you are interested in blockchain applications, start with the Composer tutorials.

2. Mining is primarily the domain of public blockchains, not permissioned blockchains like Hyperledger Fabric - again, the intro section describes it and gives information/insight into how consensus is achieved.
3. The javacript transaction processors and business logic are a constituent part of the Composer business network (ie smart contract) that is deployed to the blockchain network

Answer (score 0):

To answere to this question
In Hyperledger Fabric, you don't use a miner, how does it work without mining in a blockchain?

There is really no concept of mining in hyperledger as it is permissioned blockchain where you know who will the participants of commiting transaction.  So to reach on the consensus there is a concept of endorsement where you define who will validate the transaction. Search in below tutorial for endorsement for further details.
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blockchain.html